# How to remove header and footer from particular post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i wondering how can i remove header and footer from the one particular post. i have searched around google and wordpress but i didn't get anything which can prevent header and footer to display.

i am using memberpress plugin and i am changing the design of registration form. here i am not able to use custom template also.

i know for page we can prevent to display some of the code for that page by using following code but need help on post.

```
 if(!is_page('1'))
     //not to display
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways..

(1)create php file as 'single-PID.php' in your selected theme folder
suppose that you added post and the post id is 18(remember post id is important) and on that you don't want header and footer. so

- copy and paste single.php and u get 'single-copy.php' rename to 'single-18.php'(18 is post id).
- now in single-18.php remove `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.
- now add below function in 'function.php' file :

  ```
  function my_single_template_by_post_id( $located_template ) {
      return locate_template( array( sprintf( "single-%d.php", absint( get_the_ID() ) ), $located_template ) );
  }
  add_filter( 'single_template', 'my_single_template_by_post_id' );
  ```
- admin side ,select posts from menu ...click view on post that has id '18'

(2)create php file as 'page-PID.php' in your selected theme folder
suppose that you added page and the page(save as post type 'page' in wp-post database table) id is 8(remember post id is important) and on that you don't want header and footer. so

- copy and paste page.php and u get 'page-copy.php' rename to 'page-8.php'(8 is page id).
- now in page-8.php remove `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.
- admin side ,select pages from menu ...click view link on page that has id '8'

Comment: This is not your first post. Please properly format your posts so that others don't have to clean up your mess. Code blocks are meant for code, not text. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use is_single function just like is_page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single

Copied from Codex:

> is_single(); // When any single Post page is being displayed.
>
> is_single('17'); // When Post 17 (ID) is being displayed.
>
> is_single(17); // When Post 17 (ID) is being displayed. Integer
>   parameter also works